# How to run async functions concurrently in a for loop AND catch all errors in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, error-handling

I am trying to execute an asynchronous function on a number of items. Additionally, I want to catch all errors, that might be thrown in this function.

When running the following code, I still get an "unhandled exception" error, instead of the actual error message "some error" being printed for each item by the WriteLine statement.

```cs
public async Task RunEachItem()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        tasks.Add(SomeAsyncFunc(item.Index));
    }

    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}

public async Task SomeAsyncFunc(int index)
{
    // somehow process item using index parameter

    throw new Exception("some error");
}
```

I would be very grateful for any help, as I did not find out how to accomplish this using google, or AI tools.

Comment: You are correctly running async functions concurrently, and you are correctly catching the errors.  The only problem with this code is thinking that `e.Message` is useful.

Comment: You have two possible approaches: check `e.GetType()` and learn how to read the other properties (particularly the `InnerExceptions` collection) of what is most likely an `AggregateException`.  Or read `tasks[i].Exception` which will still be an AggregateException (but now at least you know which call caused it)

Comment: Perhaps your unhandled exception message originates from something else other than SomeAsyncFunc or Task.WhenAll. Perhaps `Items` is null, thus your foreach loop failing by throwing a NullReferenceException, and when this is unhandled, well, depending on the application type this can result in some unhandled exception message of some kind or another. Or perhaps one of the elements in the Items collections is null, thus item.Index failing with a NRE that isn't being caught either...

Comment: @BenVoigt Ok, but when replacing `e.Message` with some other message, it isn't printed either, and the error `Unhandled exception. System.Exception: some error` remains.

Comment: Move the foreach inside the `try`/`catch`.  Any exception thrown before the first `await` will need to be handled during that loop.

Comment: @jumpingSloth then you are quite likely not running exactly the same code as you have posted in your question. What does the real SomeAsyncFunc method look like that you are executing, is it really the same as in the question? Are you awaiting a call to SomeAsyncFunc in some way anywhere else you have not shown in your question?

Comment: @BenVoigt The method is shown to be `async`, so we know it will never throw, only return a faulted task.

Comment: @BenVoigt So?  It doesn't change that it can't throw.

Comment: @EyesShriveledToRaisins the exception, causing the "unhandled exception" error is definitely originating from my asynchronous function, as the error message from `new Exception("some error")` is printed with it. (like the example in my previous comment)

Comment: Does any other part of your program call `SomeAsyncFunc`?  Does `SomeAsyncFunc` start any new threads or use `Task.Run` to do work outside its own context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use property `Exception.InnerExceptions` of awaitable task that would contain all your tasks.

```
class Foo
{
    public async Task RunEachItem()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(SomeAsyncFunc(i));
        }

        Task t = null!;
        try
        {
           t = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
           await t;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            var all = t.Exception.InnerExceptions;
            foreach (Exception exception in all)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task SomeAsyncFunc(int index)
    {
        // somehow process item using index parameter

        throw new Exception($"some error {index}");
    }
}
```

The output of this code would be

```
some error 0
some error 1
some error 2
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This method works beautifully and is simpler, than the one I posted.

Answer (score -1):

After searching the depths of Google even further, I found this [this](https://thesharperdev.com/csharps-whenall-and-exception-handling/) article on the topic.
It seems like the try-catch statement around the `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` only catches the first exception. So you need to surround the asynchronous function with a "buffer call" like so:

```cs
private async Task BufferCall(int index)
{
    try
    {
       await someAsyncFunc(index);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}

// ...

tasks.Add(BufferCall(item.Index));
```

The only question now is, if the functions are still running concurrently this way...

Comment: I think it's not the proper way if the author wants to aggregate all raised exceptions at the end of the proccessing